# Applying Encryption and Hshing Algorithms for Secure Communication

Tags: encryption, hash

I'm trying to copy a file from the student's account for its gpg but when I try to type in the path all I get is this result I have tried everything, and this lab is due tomorrow.

```
cp / home/Instructor/instructor.pub/home/student/Documents/instructor.pub
```

and the results I get is `cp: omitting directory` /'`

Comment: Your question is far from clear, but I suspect you simply have the space in the wrong place and what you really want is `cp /home/Instructor/instructor.pub /home/student/Documents/instructor.pub`

Answer (score 0):

There is a space in the wrong place after the first `/` character that is causing a `cp: omitting directory /` error message. Also `/home/Instructor/instructor.pub` and `/home/student/Documents/instructor.pub` should be separated by a space character to create two separate strings, one for each location of instructor.pub.

The correct command should be as follows.

```
cp /home/Instructor/instructor.pub /home/student/Documents/instructor.pub
```